# creating new column by running a function with input from several datasets on each row

Tags: r, function, merge

I want to aggregate som data, combining two datasets lsr and adherence (examples for reproducability):

```
adherence <- cbind.data.frame(c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), c("2013.1", "2013.1", "2013.1", "2013.2", "2013.2", "2013.2"))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
names(adherence)[1] <- "ID" 
names(adherence)[2] <- "year"
adherence$year <- as.numeric(as.character(adherence$year))

lsr <- cbind.data.frame(
        c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"), #ID
        c("2012.3", "2012.8", "2013.1","2012.8", "2013.3", "2013.9", "2011", "2013"), #eksd
        c("60", "90", "90", "60", "120", "60", "30", "90") # DDD
        )
names(lsr)[1] <- "ID"
names(lsr)[2] <- "eksd"
names(lsr)[3] <- "DDD"

lsr$eksd <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$eksd))
lsr$DDD <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$DDD))
lsr$ENDDATE <- lsr$eksd + lsr$DDD/365.25
```

So in the adherence dataset I want a new column, containing information from the lsr dataset depending on the ID variable and year variable of each row in the adherence dataset. I made this function that I thinks does just that:

```
function.DDAV <- function() {
        Y <- lsr %>% #dummy variable
          filter(., .$ID == adherence$ID) %>% #filters lsr by ID from relevant row in adherence dataset
          filter(., .$eksd <= adherence$year & adherence$year <= .$ENDDATE) # filters further to include relevant time period
          Y$DIFF <- (Y$ENDDATE - adherence$year)*365.25 # calculates relevant drug dosage available for implementation of dosis regimen at time = adhererence$year i.e. uses the time from adherence dataset and compares with time until dose runs out
          z <- sum(Y$DIFF) #sum available drugs doses
          return(z) # returns sum to be inputted in one row in new column in adherence dataset
      }
```

and the I want to apply this once for every row in the adherence dataset, creating a new column using the relevant row values.

I tried using the apply family functions, and aggregate function. I've struggling with this for a few days, and I get different errors, that I haven't shown, because I think that I may be thinking about using the problem all wrong ? When searching for it I only find questions about applying over the entire row or column in one single dataset.

EDIT I show the ideal output below:
The ideal output looks like this:

adherence$adherence <- as.numeric(c("90","0","53.475","16.95","120","0"))

In essense the calculation is simple after filtering: if a row is included after filtering the values are calculated as this example from first row with adherence$ID = 1 and adherence$year = 2013.1. only the last row of ID=1 remains, the sum is (2013.1 (adherence$year)-2013.346 (lsr$ENDDATE))*365.25 = 90.

Comment: We can create `lsr` and `adherence`, but we don't know how your ideal output should look like. You have to post that in order to be able to help you.

Comment: I updated and explained my ideal output as you asked, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you are after, but hopefully it's a starting point.

My understanding is that for each occurrence of `ID` in `acceptance` you want to compare it with all like `ID`'s in lsr and if the `year` is greater than or equal to `eksd` and less than `ENDDATE` you want to do a calculation with the remaining `ENDDATE`s.

The below should work to do that, the results in `newVariable` are slightly different than those in your ideal output, in that for the value related to ID=2 and year=2013.2 there isn't an `eksd` value for ID=2 in `lsr` that is less than or equal to `year` so instead of 120 I get 0.

```
 adherence <- cbind.data.frame(c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), c("2013.1", "2013.1", "2013.1", "2013.2", "2013.2", "2013.2"))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
names(adherence)[1] <- "ID" 
names(adherence)[2] <- "year"
adherence$year <- as.numeric(as.character(adherence$year))

lsr <- cbind.data.frame(
     c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"), #ID
     c("2012.3", "2012.8", "2013.1","2012.8", "2013.3", "2013.9", "2011", "2013"), #eksd
     c("60", "90", "90", "60", "120", "60", "30", "90") # DDD
)
names(lsr)[1] <- "ID"
names(lsr)[2] <- "eksd"
names(lsr)[3] <- "DDD"

lsr$eksd <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$eksd))
lsr$DDD <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$DDD))
lsr$ENDDATE <- lsr$eksd + lsr$DDD/365.25

adherence %>% full_join(lsr, by = 'ID')  %>% mutate(newVariable = ifelse(eksd <= year & year <= ENDDATE, (ENDDATE - year) * 365.25, 0)) %>% 
     group_by(ID, year) %>% summarize(newVariable = sum(newVariable)) 

      ID   year newVariable
  <fctr>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1      1 2013.1      90.000
2      1 2013.2      53.475
3      2 2013.1       0.000
4      2 2013.2       0.000
5      3 2013.1      53.475
6      3 2013.2      16.950
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What you did is a very nice pragmatic solution. You realized that while the full_join might create irrelevant instances in the joined dataset, this didn't matter when we apply the filters. Very nice solution, that I'll be able to fit for many purposes. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this full join increases the size of the data way beyond my servers RAM. lsr alone is 90GB.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So the above solution took way way to much ressources to run on a large dataset, so I ended up with this solution:

```
function.AH <- function(x) {
  A <- subset(lsr, ID == x[1] & eksd <= x[2] & ENDDATE > x[2]) 
  if (nrow(A) == 0) {
    0
  } else {
   sum(A$ENDDATE-as.numeric(x[2]))*365.25
  } 
}

apply (adherence, 1,  FUN = function.AH)
```